# Mazel Tov li'chayim

Tags: engagement-shidduch

What is supposed to take place at a "li"chayim" that parents of a new couple make when their children get engaged?  Is there protocol for what is done as well as the guest list?

Comment: Mazal Uvracha! is the popular expression

Comment: What's the difference between this and a vort (for those that don't perform *tana'im* at the vort)? From what I have seen, it is quite informal, actually. Usually close family members and a few neighborhood friends are invited, and they serve some schnapps (hence the "lechaim" and cake / pastries. The women who tend to be more weight-conscious eat salads.